# How to print each column of strings separately in python?

Tags: python, string, text-manipulation

I have used python to print a string "aaaaabbbbbccccc" into 5 separate columns of characters. I have not used an array to do this.

```
a a a a a
b b b b b 
c c c c c
```

Now I want to print each column separately from each other, so for example print only the first column and then do this for all other columns:

```
a
b
c
```

To print the characters in 5 different columns I have used:

```
var="aaaaabbbbbccccc" 
count=0 
for char in var:   
 if count<4:
  print(char, end="  ")
  count=count+1   
 else:
  count=0
  print(char)
```

Comment: There's no "column" type in the string datatype, unless you're dealing with matrices or dataframes.

Comment: `print('\n'.join(var[::5]))`? Or even `print(*var[::5], sep='\n')`. For all columns - `for i in range(5): print(*var[i::5], sep='\n')`

Comment: Do you mean to print `a b c a b c a b c ...` in a vertical line?

Comment: What will be the final output, and how does that differ from what you already have?

Comment: @lemon the term "column" has a meaning in text layout. Since this is about formatting text and not matrices, I'd assume this meaning.

Comment: @Friedrich yes "column" in the way it appears when printed, not an actual column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure what the aim of this code is, but I have tried to stick to your existing code structure:

```
var = 'aaaaabbbbbccccc'
cnt = 0
col_to_print = 4 # change this to print a different col.
for char in var:
    if cnt == col_to_print:
        print(char)
    if cnt<4:
        cnt +=1
    else:
        cnt = 0
```

output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: And what output does it produce? Please tell us.

Comment: the exact output the question asker has requested in their second code block

Comment: Jacob's code worked for the first 4 columns, but it prints the wrong characters for the last column. In this case it printed only "a c"

Comment: well spotted, I have updated slightly, should work now